# How to call functions in one Jenkins Shared Library from another

Tags: jenkins, shared-libraries, jenkins-pipeline, jenkins-job-dsl

I have two separate libraries (Library A and Library B), I have defined them on the jenkins configuration so they can be both called from the pipeline.

From Library A I would like to call some functions/methods that are defined in Library B.

My logic tells me that I need to import and probably create an instance of Library B inside Library A before I can have access to any of Library B methods. But I have not been successful. I am no expert in Java, however any guidance is greatly appreciated.

Comment: The only way I've seen this really work is by using the `libraryResource` step to dynamically bring in another library.

Answer (score 5):

This depends on where the Libraries are are stored.

If they are under ./vars/ then you do not need to import them, as the Jenkinsfile has already imported all scripts via the `@Library('sharedLibs') _`. You would just call it, `def a = LibraryB.functionA()`

If it is under a traditional ./src/com/something/whatevas, then you would do a more traditional `import com.something.whateva.Library` at the top of the Library A

Answer (score 5):

In Jenkinsfile:

```
@Library(['libA', 'libB']) _
```

and you can call between them:

```
import org.myorg.PruebaA / import org.myorg.PruebaB
```